# Compare two images in terms of width and height

Tags: ruby, image, aspect-ratio

EDIT: I believe I didn't state correctly my question, so here is the edit.

I want to be able to compare (and score) a set of images with one image in terms of width and height.

Ideally, I would have a BASE_SCORE value (for example 100) that would be used in order to score each image depending on how close they look to the main image (in terms of width and height).

So, if for example, the main image looks like `{:width => 100, :height => 100}`, and set_images look like `[{:width => 100, :height => 100}, {:width => 10, :height => 40}]`, the first element would have a score of BASE_SCORE, because they look exactly the same.

I fail to see how to compare width/heights in order to score each element of set_images.

Comment: Are you looking to store the set_of_images aspect ratio score or just do a one-time sort? Also, you don't need the if/else statement, aspect ratio should always be width/height regardless of which is greater (which is actually what you do in that statement anyway, but yeah, it's not needed)

Comment: Do you realize that your "if/else" check does the same thing regardless of the branch?  Did you mean to switch width/height in one of them?

Comment: n_i_c_k I am willing to store that score. So, having something like BASE_SCORE = 10, and depending on the result of the comparison of aspect ratios do ``score = comparison * BASE_SCORE``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a problem with just using the Euclidean distance?  Zero represents equality:

```ruby
def euclidean_distance(a, b)
  dx = a[:width] - b[:width]
  dy = a[:height] - b[:height]
  Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy))
end

test_subject = { width: 200, height: 50 }
samples = [
  { width: 100, height: 100 },
  { width: 80,  height: 200 },
  { width: 200, height: 50 },
  { width: 10,  height: 10 }
]

distances = samples.map { |s| euclidean_distance(test_subject, s) }

samples.zip(distances) { |img, dist| puts "#{img[:width]}x#{img[:height]} => #{dist}" }
```

Output:

```
100x100 => 111.80339887498948
80x200 => 192.09372712298546
200x50 => 0.0
10x10 => 194.164878389476
```

You can then use `sort` easily enough:

```ruby
sorted = samples.sort { |a, b| euclidean_distance(test_subject, a) <=> euclidean_distance(test_subject, b) }
```

Comment: I would like to have a score in the range of 0-1 (where 1 is they are the same) that would let me multiply by a BASE_SCORE (100).

Comment: I see.  One problem that you have to appreciate is that the only images that will score zero will have infinite width and/or height (assuming you have no limit on image width/height). :)  The simplest solution is to take a function, f(x), of the Euclidean distance such that f(0) = 1, f(infinity) = 0.  One such function is e^-x, so: Math.exp(-euclidean_distance(test_sample, other_image))

Comment: To make my comment clearer: distances = samples.map { |s| Math.exp(-euclidean_distance(test_subject, s)) }

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You have a case where score is 0, and width and height are not infinite (200x50 => 0.0) - My idea is to have the score for each image in the range between 0 and 1 (1 being best score), so that I can later multiply that for a BASE_SCORE.

Comment: Ah, well you can just normalise the values then. Once you've calculated the distances as in my original answer, divide all of the distances by the maximum distance. After that, you'll have a set of numbers between 0 and 1 inclusive such that 0 means the same and 1 means most different. This is the inverse of what you want, so just subtract each of those values from 1: `m = distances.max; distances.map { |d| 1 - (d / m) }`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work.  Excuse the formatting...

```
$ cat foo.rb
require 'pp'

main_image = {:width => 100, :height => 50}
set_of_images = [{:width => 200, :height => 300, :id => 2}, 
                 {:width => 100, :height => 50, :id => 9}]

aspect_ratio = main_image[:width] / main_image[:height].to_f

sorted_images = set_of_images.
                  map{|i| i[:score] = (aspect_ratio - i[:width]/i[:height].to_f).abs; i}.
                  sort_by{|i| i[:score]}

pp sorted_images

$ ruby foo.rb
[{:width=>100, :height=>50, :id=>9, :score=>0.0},
 {:width=>200, :height=>300, :id=>2, :score=>1.3333333333333335}]
```

Comment: How would I score the result though? In a way that the scores reflect how close/far an aspect ratio is from the main aspect ratio? That's why I was thinking on having a BASE_SCORE = 10, and then if I could have each image with a "comparison" value ranging from 0 to 1 (this value would reflect how similar the images look in terms of width and height), I could do score = comparison_value * BASE_SCORE

Comment: In that case, map the input to include say :score, then sort by that.  The score IMHO would just be the difference b/n the main ratio and this images ratio.  The closer to zero, the better the score.

Comment: thanks, but your code is giving a score of 0 to an image that has the same width and height than the main image, right?

Comment: @HommerSmith Yes.  As I said.. the closer to zero, the better the score.

Comment: But then how would I use a BASE_SCORE? I would like to be able to have the score between a 0-1 range, so I can have a BASE SCORE and do BASE_SCORE * actual_score..